# How to limit the the number of row retrieved from an associated table in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Assuming two database tables: `Funds` and `Prices`, in which `Funds hasMany Prices`.

What I wanted to do is to retrieve the latest 15 prices of a particular fund in a certain scenario. Is there a means in CakePHP to make a `$this->Fund->find('all')` call that would allow me to limit the number of rows to be retrieved from the associated `Price` table?

*Note that I prefer not setting the `'limit'` option in the `Fund` model's `$hasMany` variable.*

**Note on accepted answer [Nov 2]:**

[In Jason's answer which I had accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657363/how-to-limit-the-the-number-of-row-retrieved-from-an-associated-table-in-cakephp/1657391#1657391), I personally opt for the `bindModel` solution as I felt despite feeling a bit “hack-y”, it bodes much better with me as to make a one-off override on the default Model bindings.

The code I used is as follows:

```
$this->Fund->bindModel(array(
    'hasMany' => array(
        'Price' => array(
            'limit' => 15,
            'order' => 'Price.date DESC'
        )
    )
);
```

No `unbindModel` is necessary. More information could be read from [“3.7.6.6 Creating and Destroying Associations on the Fly”](http://book.cakephp.org/view/86/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly) in the CakePHP manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, you don't want to set the limit statically in the model.  If you wish to use a hasMany association, there really isn't any other way that I'm aware of other than changing that limit one way or another.

Here are a few ways to dynamically change it:

1. You could change the limit with a call to Funds->bindModel().  (This may require an unbindModel() first, but I can't remember for certain)
2. You could add a function to Funds to change the limit directly. (See example below.)
3. If you're feeling ambitious, you could write a Behavior to add the functionality to specify it per find() call similarly to [the Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable).

**Example for #2**

```
<?php
function setPriceLimit($limit = 10) {
     // Assuming the association is 'Price'
     $this->hasMany['Price']['limit'] = $limit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Containable behavior to accomplish this easily.

- in your AppModel or Fund model add :

  ```
  var $actsAs = array('Containable');
  ```
- then in your controller you can add the 'contain' option to your find('all') :

  ```
  $this->Fund->find('all', array(
      'contain' => array(
          'Price' => array(
              'limit' => 15,
              'order' => 'Price.date DESC')
  )));
  ```

More information is available in the book : http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable

Answer (score 0):

Your $this->Model->find('all') could include conditions.  ie.

$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Model.field' => $value), 'limit' => 15));

For more info check the cake docs.

[Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the correct answer. The 'limit' parameter in find is to limit the number of row retrieve for the specified model but it doesn't restrict the number of rows to be retrieved in the associated model (in this case, I wanted to restrict the number of rows in Price)